# GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES texture render in fragment shader

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, egl

Eh .. I am using OpenGL ES on Android . 
I want to use a `SurfaceTexture` and `camera.setPreviewTexture` get camera preview texture , and use it and render this texture on screen .

Here is my question , I use a `samplerExternalOES` type to declare a sampler   in fragment shader source . And I googled some articles tell me that the `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` usually use to YUV data , and I think the shader didn't convert YUV to RGB . The fragment shader is process all fragment , the function is same . and it can works well , why ?

and How can I convert YUV to RGB format with shader ?
Thanks and please forgive my poor english.

Fragment shader Code :

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
 precision mediump float;
 uniform samplerExternalOES uInputTex;
 varying vec2 vTexCoord;
 void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(uInputTex,vTexCoord).rgb,1.0f);
 }
```

Comment: If the external texture functionality works properly, you should get RGB in the shader when you sample, without having to do anything about it. That's a main part of the extension, supporting to sample RGB colors from an image that may be stored in YUV format.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Thanks for you reply , I think I can get RGB colors from external sampler  too , but when fragment finished I can got RGB colors in framebuffer , right ? But I got a Segment fault while running glReadPixels. If i input texture is 400x400 . I suppose there is not have such 400x400x4(RGBA format) bytes and cause that error , Do you know why ? or , have can I deal with this , I just want to use this framebuffer as a texure .